# rewriteRule slash at end and improvement

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /news.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Here i can reach the website with http://domain.tld/news/de but i can't reach them with http://domain.tld/news/de/ (backslash at the end).

How can i make that?

Second Question is how can i short this 3 rules into one, because it handles all the same page?

```
# News
RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /news.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]*)$ /news.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /news.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an optional trailing slash and optionally turn `MultiViews` off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank yiou, i wil test this, another thing how can i rewrite news.php to domain.tld/news/ befor this 3 rules?

Comment: That will be `RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php [L]` as first rule.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` the problem here is that the lang-get dont work with / at the end, without no problems? why that?

Comment: I works but firefox have a strange bevaviour it adds `news/en/news/` (news/) to the end, why?

`Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php [L]

RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
`

Comment: You must understand basic thing first. Rewrite rules cannot behave differently for different browsers. If certain browser is showing wrong results it is most likely due to browser cache. Good way to test is in Chrome developer tool by disabling cache off.

Comment: You should place your full .htaccess in your question. Also I believe `/news/de/` is a physical directory?